# Finding the adjoint of $\alpha: p(X)\to(X+1)p(X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $V = \mathbb{C}[X]$ and define an inner product on $V$ by setting
$$
\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iX^i,\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_iX^i\right\rangle=
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i\bar{b_i}.$$

Let $\alpha$ be the endomorphism of $V$ defined by $\alpha : p(X) \to (X+1)p(X)$. Calculate $\alpha^*$, or show that it does not exist. ($\alpha^*$ is adjoint of $\alpha$)

Let $p(X), \:q(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$, hence there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $p(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i$, and $q(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i$.

Now, by the assumption we have

\begin{align}
\left\langle \alpha(p(X)),q(X)\right\rangle
&=\left\langle (X+1)\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i, \sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i\right\rangle \\
&=\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^{i+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i,\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i
\right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^{i+1},\:\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i\right\rangle+
\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i,\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i\right\rangle \\
&=(0+a_0\bar b_1+a_1\bar b_2\dots +a_{n-1}\bar b_{n}+0)+(a_0\bar b_0\dots+a_n\bar b_n)\\
&=a_0(\bar b_1+\bar b_0)+\dots+a_{n-1}(\bar b_{n-1}+\bar b_n)+a_{n}(0+\bar b_n)
\end{align}

I'm stuck on the rest, I'm not sure if it's true to say
$$a_0(\bar b_1+\bar b_0)+\dots+a_{n-1}(\bar b_{n-1}+\bar b_n)+a_{n}(0+\bar b_n)=$$ 
$$\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i,\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^i\right\rangle +\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_iX^i,\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_iX^{i+1}\right\rangle.$$
Hence, $\alpha^*:p(X)\to (X+1)p(X)$ and $\alpha $ is selfadjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for a polynomial $f(X)=a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_nX^n$, we have
$$
\langle f(X),X^k\rangle=a_k
$$
so, if $f_n(X)=\alpha^*(X^n)$, we have
$$
\langle f_n(X),X^k\rangle=
\langle X^n,\alpha(X^k)\rangle=
\langle X^n,X^{k+1}+X^k\rangle=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $k=n$}\\
1 & \text{if $k=n-1$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular we should have
$$
\alpha^*(1)=1,\quad
\alpha^*(X)=1+X\quad
\dots,\quad
\alpha^*(X^n)=X^{n-1}+X^n,\quad
\dotsc
$$

Can you go on?

---

If you want a representation of $\alpha*$ in terms of polynomial operations, note that
$$
\alpha^*(a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_nX^n)=
a_0+a_1+a_1X+a_2X+a_2X^2+\dotsb=
\frac{p(X)-p(0)}{X}+p(X)
$$
where the division is possible because $p(X)-p(0)$ has no constant term.

Comment: I think I got what you mean and now it makes sense to me, but I don't know how to represent it. Isn't it like $\alpha^*:p(x)\to (1+\frac{1}{X})p(X)$?

Comment: but in this case $\alpha^*$ isn't an  endomorphism.

Comment: @Parisina It's not necessary that one can represent $\alpha^*$ by a multiplication.

Comment: @Parisina No, it doesn't work. You *can* interpret $\alpha^*(p(X))=(1+X^{-1})p(X)$, with the convention that negative powers of $X$ are thrown away.